# Involuntary conversion of int64 to float64 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Never mind the below--I see the cause of the problem.  The shift of course produces a N/A.

I want to prevent a type conversion that occurs when concatenating a dataframe to itself horizontally.  I have a dataframe where all columns are int64 (and the index is a datetime64[ns]):

```
df.dtypes
Out[118]: 
op        int64
```

I concatenate to have the next row's columns (suffixed with "_next") appear on the same line as the current row:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).add_suffix('_next')], axis=1)
```

But then the types on the concatenated columns change to float64:

```
df.dtypes
Out[122]: 
op               int64
op_next        float64
```

Is there a way to prevent that type conversion?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because `df.shift(-1)` has one element which is `NaN`, which is a `float`. Such a series will automatically be upcasted to `float`. Here is a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'op': [1, 2, 3]})
df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).add_suffix('_next')], axis=1)

print(df)

   op  op_next
0   1      2.0
1   2      3.0
2   3      NaN
```

There is nothing you can do except use `fillna` to fill with an integer and recast. You can do this either before or after `pd.concat`:

**Before**

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).fillna(0).astype(int).add_suffix('_next')], axis=1)
```

**After**

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).add_suffix('_next')], axis=1)
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shift produces a n/a value, forcing the float64.