# Unwanted type conversion pandas apply (int64 --> float64)

Tags: python, pandas, types, int64

Why do pandas convert automatically `int64` to `float64`?
I've checked out these questions:

- [Involuntary conversion of int64 to float64 in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300983/involuntary-conversion-of-int64-to-float64-in-pandas)
- [Unwanted automatic type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300983/involuntary-conversion-of-int64-to-float64-in-pandas)
- [Pandas Dtypes : float64 to 'Object' Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851447/pandas-dtypes-float64-to-object-conversion)

but none of them are as simple as my case as far as I understood.
I am running the code on Jupyter lab.

```py
>>> df.dtypes
cd_fndo      int64
dif        float64
dtype: object
```

so the types are `int64` and `float64`. However applying the identity function results in type change:

```py
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x, axis=1).dtypes
cd_fndo    float64
dif        float64
dtype: object
```

However, when considering only the first column, the type `int64` remains the same:

```py
>>> df.iloc[:, :1].apply(lambda x: x, axis=1).dtypes
cd_fndo    int64
dtype: object
```

Could someone please explain the causes of this type change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.apply(lambda x: x, axis=1)` means the lambda is mapped to each row. The row contains an int and a float hence it's converted to float to accommodate both elements.

In the second example, the row only contains 1 int so no conversion is needed.

Comment: Oh, this happens because both are stored in a `pd.Series`, right? So I suppose the dtype would be `object` if at least one of the columns has string elements..